# Finding the Jordan form and basis for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I have this matrix $A=\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
-3&3&-2\\
-7&6&-3\\
1&-1&2\\
\end{array} } \right]$

I computed the characteristic polynomial $C_A(t)=-(t-2)^2(t-1)$

When I go to try and find the eigenvectors and generalized eigenvectors I compute $A-2I=\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
-5&3&-2\\
-7&4&-3\\
1&-1&0\\
\end{array} } \right]$

Using row reduction $\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
1&-1&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&0\\
\end{array} } \right]x=0$ gives me eigenvectors having the form $e=r\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
-1\\
\end{array} } \right]$

$v=\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
-1\\
\end{array} } \right]$
Is the only eigenvector up to a constant. So I know there is 1 generalized eigenvector and I simply chose this eigenvector to be my initial vector in the cycle.

At this point I know the Jordan form is $J=\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
2&1&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{array} } \right]$

Now to find the generalized eigenvector I can take an augmented matrix
$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
 5&3&-2&1\\  
 -7&4&1&1\\
1&-1&0&-1  
\end{array}\right)$
I row reduced this to the form
 $\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
 1 & -1 & 0&-1\\  
 0 & 1 & 1&2\\
0&0&0&0  
\end{array}\right)$

So I need a vector that satisfies $x_1-x_2=-1$ and $x_2+x_3=2$ I let $x_3=1$

Which gives me a vector $x=\left(\begin{array}{c}  
 0\\  
 1\\
1 
\end{array}\right)$ which seems to work, so I have a basis for the generalized eigenspace for $\lambda=2$

then I need to find a solution for $(A-I)x=0$ for $\lambda=1$.

I row reduce $A-I=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}  
 -4&3&-2\\  
 -7&5&1\\
1&-1&1  
\end{array}\right]$ to get $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}  
 1&0&-1\\  
 0&1&-2\\
0&0&0  
\end{array}\right]$ and using $(A-I)x=0$ found that all eigenvectors for $\lambda=1$ have the form $v=s\left(\begin{array}{c}  
1\\  
2\\
1 
\end{array}\right)$

So I can make a matrix $Q=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}  
 1&1&0\\  
 2&1&1\\
1&-1&1  
\end{array}\right]$ s.t $A=QJQ^{-1}$ where the columns of $Q$ are a jordan basis for $J$

Comment: I stopped reading at the first unclear point: given the characteristic polynomial, how can you be sure that the Jordan normal form is what you have provided? Can't it be the diagonal matrix with $2,2,1$ in the diagonal?

Comment: Yes I fixed this. I dont know that until I know the geometric multiplicity of that eigenvalue is 1.

Comment: Which you can figure out by solving the system of linear equations $(A-2I)x=0$. Try that! (Or compute the rank of $A-2I$ at least, that also helps.)

Comment: I found an eigenvector. My problem is finding the generalized eigenvector. I tried to use this eigenvector I found , $v$ and then compute $(A-2I)(x)=v$.

Comment: You are not focusing on the main point of my comment: compute the rank, and if it is $2$, you need to find $2$ independent eigenvectors, not just one. In that case, the Jordan normal form is diagonal. (You still seem to work under the assumption that the Jordan form has a $2\times 2$ block, which it might not...)

Comment: It does have a $2\text{x}2$ block though. When I try to find eigenvectors I get that for $(A-2I)x=0$ the components of $x$ must satisfy $x_1-x_2=0$, $x_2+x_3=0$ so there is only 1 free variable I can choose, which means my geometric multiplicity is 1.

Comment: You need a solution to $(A-2I)x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ to get an element $x\in ker(A-2I)^2\backslash ker(A-2I)$ which is not the same as using the reduced form, since this is no homogeneous system anymore

Comment: OK, good. So up to the point where you found the essentially unique eigenvector $u=(1,1,-1)$ with eigenvalue $2$, everything is correct. In order to find the second basis vector $v$ in the $2$-simensional invariant subspace, you need to solve the equation $Av=2v+u$. You do not seem to be doing that at the end of your post.

Comment: Oh ok so could I row reduce an augmented matrix using $(A-2I)\vert (1//1//-1)$?

Comment: Yes, that would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are looking for a Jordan canonical basis, $Ax = 2x+v$, where $x$ is the generalized eigenvector you're looking for. Equivalently, $(A-2I)x = v$. Applying $A-2I$ one more time to each side will give you the following statement: $(A-2I)^{2}x = 0$.

So, your generalized eigenvector is in the nullspace of $(A-2I)^2$, and it is not in the nullspace of $(A-2I)$. Can you finish from there?

Comment: I believe I finished.